# Interface method with parameter of same interface type as declaring type

Tags: java, oop, interface, casting

**Background**

I'm building a chess program in Java.

**Issue**

I created an interface type called `IPiece`:

```
public interface IPiece
{
    boolean isFriendlyTo(IPiece piece);
    Square[] destinationsFrom(IBasicBoard onBoard, Square fromSquare);
}
```

I'm implementing it as such:

```
public abstract class AbstractChessPiece implements IPiece
{
    private PieceArchetype pieceArchetype;
    private Color color;

    public AbstractChessPiece(PieceArchetype pieceArchetype, Color color)
    {
        this.pieceArchetype = pieceArchetype;
        this.color = color;
    }

    public PieceArchetype archetype()
    {
        return this.pieceArchetype;
    }

    public Color color()
    {
        return this.color;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isFriendlyTo(IPiece piece)
    {
        if(this.equals(piece))
            return true;

        return this.isFriendlyTo((AbstractChessPiece) piece);
    }

    public boolean isFriendlyTo(AbstractChessPiece piece)
    {
        return this.color() == piece.color();
    }

    @Override
    public abstract Square[] destinationsFrom(IBasicBoard onBoard, Square fromSquare);
}
```

The question I have regards the `isFriendlyTo(IPiece)` method. Is it a bad design to include this method in the `IPiece` interface, because it requires a cast for any derived types. There's no way to calculate the result without casting. It just seems awkward. I always second guess a design when casting is involved.

Comment: Why not include an accessor `getColor` in `IPiece`? Then there's no need to cast...

Comment: @wakjah I thought of that, but I'm exploring the possibility of reusing the interface to build other non-chess game types where piece friendliness is not determined by color.

Comment: Could you ever have an object that is an `IPiece` but not an `AbstractChessPiece`? If that never happens, then I don't think you need `IPiece`.

Comment: Never mind, you just answered my question :)

Comment: Then perhaps this should be an operation on the `Player` class instead? (assuming you have one of these)

Comment: @musical_coder You bring up a good point though. Ideally, all the pieces loaded into a game would inherit from `AbstractChessPiece`, which forces anyone re-implementing pieces specifically for a chess game to inherit from `AbstractChessPiece`. I guess that's not necessarily bad as long as it's documented?

Comment: @wakjah I do have a `Player` class. I didn't think of including it there. I'll have to explore that option.

Comment: Nope, document it carefully and that would work. I actually think that using just `AbstractChessPiece` is the way to go here. It's good that you're thinking about future reuse, but would it really be that beneficial to try to fit an interface to two games with different rules and pieces? Seems like a little too much "premature optimization".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want to keep this interface structure, you could add a generic type to the interface. which defines which pieces it can be hostile to. It is what the `Comparable` interface does, and works like this:

```
public interface IPiece<E> {
  boolean isFriendlyTo(E piece);
  ...
}
public abstract class AbstractChessPiece implements IPiece<AbstractChessPiece> {
  ...
  @Override
  public boolean isFriendlyTo(AbstractChessPiece piece) {
    return this.color() == piece.color();
  }
  ...
}
```

I would however go with wakjah and recommend that the interface declared a `getColor` or perhaps a `getPlayer` method.

You should only use the same interface in two different situations, if they interact with each other in some way (e.g. checkers pieces and chess pieces could suddenly play together). In your case it seems that the game-play mechanics are totally disjoint, so it make sense to use different interfaces for that.

If you use the same code to render graphics for both games, then you can define another interface that does not include game-play methods like `isFriendlyTo`. This will separate shared graphic functionality form disjoint game-play functionality.